# EventTrigger and DataTrigger not working together

Tags: c#, wpf, storyboard, datatrigger, eventtrigger

I have a Collection of items I want to display in an `ItemsControl`.
When an item is new it should fade in and when its `StateType` property changes to "Finished" it should fade out.

The `ItemTemplate`of my `ItemsControl` is a `DockPanel`

```xml
<DockPanel.Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DockPanel}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <!-- Fades in as expected but DataTrigger below never fades out -->
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="0:0:1" From="0" To="1"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>

    <!-- Using this for fading in everything works fine (first StateType of a new item is Running) -->
    <!--
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding StateType}" Value="{x:Static local:AppStateItem+Type.Running}">
        <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="0:0:1" From="0" To="1"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
    </DataTrigger>
    -->
            <!-- fade out trigger -->
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding StateType}" Value="{x:Static local:AppStateItem+Type.Finished}">
                <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="0:0:1" From="1" To="0" BeginTime="0:0:4"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</DockPanel.Style>
```

Problem is: It fades in but never fades out. If I replace the `EventTrigger` with the commented `DataTrigger` for fading in it works as expected. Is the `EventTrigger` overriding something even it should only fire once?

Answer (score 0):

Your example works just fine with two `DataTriggers`.

Make sure that you implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and raise the `PropertyChanged` event for the `StateType` property.

You may also want to remove the `BeginTime` setting from the second `Storyboard`.

Try this minimal reproducible sample:

**MainWindow.xaml:**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <DockPanel>
        <DockPanel.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DockPanel}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding StateType}" Value="{x:Static local:AppStateItem.Running}">
                        <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard >
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="0:0:1" From="0" To="1"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <!-- fade out trigger -->
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding StateType}" Value="{x:Static local:AppStateItem.Finished}">
                        <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="0:0:1" From="1" To="0" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </DockPanel.Style>
        <Button Content="Fade out" Click="Button_Click" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" />
        <TextBlock FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold" Text="test" />
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs:**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
    }

    private AppStateItem _stateType;
    public AppStateItem StateType
    {
        get { return _stateType; }
        set { _stateType = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged; 
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        StateType = AppStateItem.Finished;
    }
}

public enum AppStateItem
{
    Running,
    Finished
}
```

Comment: Yes, the two DataTriggers work. But the combination EventTrigger/DataTrigger does not work for me. I originally wanted to fade in on "Loaded"

Comment: Why not use two data triggers?

Comment: At the moment I use them. But it's a little bit workaround. I didn't want it to be dependend for a starting state. I also have "Waiting" for example. Second problem is: when state changes before fade in is done completely it stops. I workarounded this by setting a fast animation to opacitity 1 at the fade out trigger. These aniamtions are a little bit trial and error for me.

Comment: It sounds like you should create the animations programmatically rather than relying on XAML constructs.